# In the Haworth projections of D and L glucose, is the stereochemistry at every carbon except the anomeric carbon just inverted?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, carbohydrates

I'm having a bit of trouble grasping sugar stereochemistry.

Using glucose as an example, if you cyclize D and L glucose, is the stereochemistry at every carbon just inverted from the other form?

Like for example, on carbon 2 for D glucose, the hydroxyl is down. On carbon 2 for L glucose, the hydroxyl would be up.

Is this trend true for every hydroxyl or $\ce{CH2OH}$ group except the one on the anomeric carbon?

Answer (score 2):

Glucose is the hexose that projects its hydroxyl groups at positions C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>4</sub> as well as its CH<sub>2</sub>OH off C<sub>6</sub> in the equatorial direction (in its low energy conformer that is). In the β and α configurations, its anomeric carbon C<sub>1</sub> projects the hydroxyl in the equatorial and axial direction, respectively.

The D and L forms are mirror images in which all anomeric carbons have the opposite configuration between the two forms as:
[image: glucose]

Here are the equivalent structures using the Haworth projection.
[image: Glucose]